# subset h2o frame in python

Tags: python, subset, h2o

how can I subset a h2o frame in python.
if x is a df & Origin is a variable then in pandas we generally can do subsetting by

```
x[x.Origin == 'AAF']
```

but with h2o frame it gives the following error:
"H2OResponseError: Server error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  Error: Name lookup of 'x.hex' failed"

Answer (score 12):

There are a number of different ways to slice an H2OFrame, row-wise.  The methods are outlined in the H2O User Guide section on [Slicing Rows](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/slicing-rows.html).

Here is an Python example of subsetting an H2OFrame based on a column being set to a particular value using the Iris dataset:

```
import h2o
h2o.init()

# Load data
path = "http://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/iris/iris_wheader.csv"
df = h2o.import_file(path=path)

# Subset data
mask = df["class"] == "Iris-setosa"
newdf = df[mask, :]

# equivalent to both of these, which also work
# newdf = df[df["class"] == "Iris-setosa", :]
# newdf = df[df["class"] == "Iris-setosa"]
```

The `newdf = df[df["class"] == "Iris-setosa"]` version is almost identical to the format you have above, except H2OFrames do not support referencing a column like this: `df.class`; you must use: `df["class"]`.