# How to select rows from a python H2O data frame based on column values?

Tags: python, dataframe, subset, h2o

How can I subset a h2o frame in python based on a list, rather than [a single value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45832671/subset-h2o-frame-in-python)?
For example, in R one would use `%in%`, or in panda [I can see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values) one can use `.isin()`.
I'd like to do something like this, if it makes sense:

```
df.loc[df['column name'].isin(pickTheseValues)]
```

How does it work in h2o? Alternatively, can I cast the h2o data frame into panda and do the operation as above?

Answer (score 1):

h2o provides slicing rows on dataframe for both R and Python so you can use ***isin*** method to filter rows based on a column.

```
mask = df["column name"].isin(pickTheseValues)
cols = df[mask,:]
```

You can reach the details by [this](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/slicing-rows.html#slicing-rows) link.